# Xamarin Forms: Android: Toast Notifications Clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am on the most current version of Xamarin Forms. I have a Content Page. The Content Page has a content that has a Button. That Button has Button_Clicked event Which you can see below. I use IToastNitificator (https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin), and I try to pass when I send this notification after I close my app, and after I clicked the Notification my App doesn't pop up Again. Anybody can help me how can I reach this?

This is my Button_Clicked method:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var notificator = DependencyService.Get<IToastNotificator>();
        var options = new NotificationOptions()
        {
            Title = "Teszt",
            Description = "Önnek teszteket kell kitöltenie!",
            IsClickable = true
        };
        var result = await notificator.Notify(options);
        if(result.Action == NotificationAction.Clicked)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new QuestionPage());
        }
    }
```

I registered this Dependency and It's working fine.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar; 

        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ToastNotification>();
        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<OpenAppAndroid>();

        ToastNotification.Init(this);
        BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init(this);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        LoadApplication (new Spirocco.App (BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.ObtainDefaultAdapter(ApplicationContext)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this NuGet package: https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

Comment: Yes I updated my question you can see the MainActivity

Comment: This isn't help to me:(

Comment: Yes I use the same order.

Comment: Shortly I Want to back my app to Foreground when I click my Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reopen the Android application you need to set the `ForceOpenAppOnNotificationTap` to true in the `AndroidOptions`

Example:

```
var options = new NotificationOptions()
{
    Title = "Teszt",
    Description = "Önnek teszteket kell kitöltenie!",
    IsClickable = true,
    AndroidOptions = new AndroidOptions()
    {
        ForceOpenAppOnNotificationTap = true
    }
};
```

Comment: Thx I'm coming with a beer. :D
I have to do this when Timer is reach some point. Do you have any idea how can I reach this, not with click?

Comment:  Yes please ;-)  `I have to do this when Timer is reach some point` I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: When Application is Running or don't I have to run a Timer which send a Notificiation if the Timer reach some point.

Comment: @TamásDeák You could write an Android foreground `Service`, but I would do this via the `AlarmManager`, set an alarm for some time in the future, have it send a broadcast to a `BroadCastReceiver` subclass in your application and have the `OnReceive` of that receiver send your notification (and re-schedule the next alarm of needed)

Comment: @TamásDeák Make it a six-pack and its party time:       

Comment: I raised it because 1 beer is not beer haHAA